# Error in MySQL Query (Banned Word?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySQL query, which returns an error message. I think it could be due to the word "out". Normally, I would just change the field name but I am working on some software that I am not used to and I don't know how much of a change that would be. So, I want to be sure if I have to.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM probid_bids WHERE auctionid=73 AND out=0 AND invalid=0
```

Here the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out=0 AND invalid=0' at line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OUT` is indeed a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You can encase the column names in backticks to quote the names, and thus avoid this problem, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM probid_bids WHERE `auctionid`=73 AND `out`=0 AND `invalid`=0
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the cause of the error, and explaining why the OP needs to escape `out` with backticks. I'm sick of one line answers, so thank you for posting one with a bit of detail.

Answer (score 3):

`OUT` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) (it is used to specify the type of parameters -- IN, OUT, INOUT -- when creating [procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)). Try enclosing it inside backticks (`` ` ``).

The rules regarding how and when to quote the identifiers (table names, column names, etc) are [described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Note: certain MySQL configurations allow you to use double quotes as well but this should be avoided; stick with using backticks to quote identifiers and single quotes to quote strings.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the keys:

```
SELECT * FROM `probid_bids` WHERE `auctionid`=73 AND `out`=0 AND `invalid`=0
```